# how to join two data frames in pyspark in a given date range

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark

I have the following two levels of pyspark dataframes:

```
df1
client date    dateM1  dateM3  dateP3
123    9-2021  8-2021   6-2021  12-2021
124    8-2022  7-2022   5-2022  11-2022
125    2-2022  1-2022  11-2021   5-2022


df2
client    date   imp   con
123     5-2021   2     0
123     6-2021   4     1
123    10-2021   1     0
124    11-2022   1     1
124    10-2022   2     0
125     8-2022   1     1
```

I want to find the total impressions and converts for a client if they fall within a range of Range1(dateM3 to dateM1) and Range2(date to dateP3). I want to avoid a cross join of the two sets to compare the dates.

The resultant data should be something like this:

```
df
client imp_Range1 con_Range1 imp_Range2 con_Range2
123    4          1          1          0  
124    0          0          3          1
```

If no imp and con fall in the given range, it should not be a part of the final set

P.s.: the dates are in a string format as (M-yyyy)

Comment: What's your current approach? Could you show the code? Spark supports conditional joining.

Answer (score 0):

Importing necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, sum, to_date
```

1. Casting dates from StringType to DateType

```
cast_date = lambda df, column: df.withColumn(column, to_date(column, "M-yyyy"))

df1 = df1 \
    .transform(cast_date, "dateM3") \
    .transform(cast_date, "dateM1") \
    .transform(cast_date, "date") \
    .transform(cast_date, "dateP3")

df2 = df2.transform(cast_date, "date")
```

2. Join and perform groupby sum using condition statement

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2, "client")

condition1 = col("dateChng").between(col("dateM3"), col("dateM1"))
condition2 = col("dateChng").between(col("date"), col("dateP3"))

conditional_sum = lambda condition, col_name, col_alias: sum(when(condition, col(col_name)).otherwise(0)).alias(col_alias)

joined_df = joined_df.groupBy("client").agg(
    conditional_sum(condition1, "imp", "imp_range1"),
    conditional_sum(condition1, "con", "con_range1"),
    conditional_sum(condition2, "imp", "imp_range2"),
    conditional_sum(condition2, "con", "con_range2")
)

filter_cond = "imp_range1!=0 OR con_range1!=0 OR imp_range2!=0 OR con_range2!=0"

joined_df.filter(filter_cond).show()
```

**Output:**

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|client|imp_range1|con_range1|imp_range2|con_range2|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   123|         4|         1|         1|         0|
|   124|         0|         0|         3|         1|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```